# Why is javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor.init so often "synchronous"?

Tags: java, synchronized, annotation-processing

I see a lot of classes that extend `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor`,
and override the `init` member, making it synchronous.

For example: https://github.com/weibocom/motan/blob/master/motan-core/src/main/java/com/weibo/api/motan/transport/async/MotanAsyncProcessor.java#L61

I picture this function being called exclusively by the javac compiler, and if "synchronous" were necessary, I would expect to see something about it in Oracle's documentation of `AbstractProcessor` (but I do not).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html for reference.

Also, while I see `init` synchronous, I don't see `process` synchronous.

Oracle's documentation about the `init` member does say, "An IllegalStateException will be thrown if this method is called more than once on the same object."  But I don't see how that would figure in.  I guess I can imagine a scenario where we want to be careful that exactly one thread calls `init` successfully (thus synchronize), and then only that successful thread gets to call `process`.  But that's quite a flight of imagination without documentation to back it up.

So, is it necessary to specify "synchronous" for our `init` members of classes inherited from `AbstractProcessor`?  Why or why not?  And if it is necessary, why isn't it necessary to make `process` synchronous too?

Anyone have any insight?

Thanks! - Jim

Comment: Just to note: [`AbstractProcessor` defines `init` as `synchronized`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/65137ff02c015891a2e1ecb9da03919f0a675cf2/src/java.compiler/share/classes/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.java#L158).

Comment: @Slaw, Good find.  Thank you.  I’d been looking at the API docs, not the source.  I still wonder why, but now at least I see where people are getting it from.  Put it as an answer and I’ll mark it accepted.